# Cannot upgrade xenserver,pool master changes automatically to other server

Tags: linux, virtualization, xenserver

I need to upgrade my XenServer pool of servers from 5.6 to 6.1. The problem i am facing is that when i shutdown pol master to boot it from CD, then it other member in the pool become the pool master automatically, and to upgrade the XenServer, we have to start upgrade from pool master, then other members need to be upgraded.

is there any way i can upgrade pool master first? by disabling the automatic change of pool master to other member server in that pool?

Thanks

Comment: The pool master role does not typically automatically transfer when the master goes offline.  Rather, the other nodes in the pool will go into "emergency mode" until the pool master comes back online or an admin forcefully makes a node the new master.  How are you shutting down the master node?